# Generate Sources and Update Folders For All Projects

Tags: git, maven, intellij-idea, ide

There's an IntelliJ command named exactly like my title: *Generate Sources and Update Folders For All Projects*. What does that do? I might have did a huge mistake by clicking on it before asking what that does. It's now running for more than half an hour. Wont stop and I'm too afraid to stop it.

What I wanted to do is switch to another GIT branch, but the workspace crapped itself and resulted in some build errors, so I thought I would click on everything that looks like a [recycle icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/an5TB.png). So I pressed this one on the maven panel: [image: Generate Sources and Update Folders For All Projects].

Does it do anything special? It clearly works much longer than an

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

What anything other would I need? Actually until now I didn't even need anything other than that.

ps. (It has finished now, but I'm still curious what that functionality really is.)

Answer (score 4):

The thing about generating sources is that its both a **pre-build** task (so that IntelliJ can access those generated sources for linting etc), and a **build** task (because these sources are not in source control and need to be generated with each build).
So IntelliJ has this button to **Generate sources and Update Folders** while Maven has a **generate-sources** phase in its default lifecycle. They ALMOST do the same thing.

Whether sources have been generated or not, IntelliJ needs to know where to import from. You can set that here

`File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing`

When you build your project, Maven generates the sources, but IntelliJ still doesn't know that it should import them. That's why the button has two actions in one. Alternatively, you can right-click your target/generated-sources directory and select "Mark directory as > Generated sources root". It should turn blue. But using the button is better, since it will use any custom directories configured in your source-generating plugin (provided your imports are configured to "detect automatically").

The **Generate Sources and Update Folders** action doesn't appear in the **Build Output** or **Event log**, but it will show briefly in the **Background Tasks** window. If you want to see what it did, open your version of my *~/.cache/JetBrains/IdeaIE2021.1/log/idea.log* file. IntelliJ appears to invoke the source-generating plugin directly (outside a lifecycle).

Note these open issues though:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-90730
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-252499

Answer (score 2):

Per the [IntelliJ IDEA Maven FAQ](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Maven+Integration+FAQ#MavenIntegrationFAQ-GeneratedSources):

> In order to get generated sources automatically imported as source
>   folders configure corresponding plugins so that they put them into
>   target/generated-sources/, where subdir is any folder name you
>   prefer. The subdir folder is necessary to distinguish sources from
>   different tools and also to exclude some special generated sources
>   (e.g. groovy stubs).
>
> Please note that even if you manually configure some source folders
>   under target/generated-sources of this folder itself, IDEA will
>   rewrite them according to your pom.xml.
>
> Any time you want to generate sources you simply execute the
>   corresponding goal, bound for generation (usually generate-sources,
>   generate-test-sources). After that IDEA will pick up new folders and
>   set them up.

Per [Maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-generating-sources.html):

> Let's run though a short example to try and help. To generate sources
>   you must first have a plugin that participates in the generate-sources
>   phase like the ANTLR4 Maven Plugin.
>
> So this is all fine and dandy, we have a plugin that wants to generate
>   some sources from a Antlr4 grammar but how do we use it. You need to
>   specify that you want to use it in your POM: If you then type mvn
>   compile Maven will walk through the lifecycle and will eventually hit
>   the generate-sources phase and see you have a plugin configured that
>   wants to participate in that phase and the ANTLR4 Maven Plugin is
>   executed with your given configuration. Furthermore during the compile
>   you can observe that all the generated code (from your grammar files)
>   will automatically being compiled without supplemental configuration.

As you can see **Generate Sources** action runs the `generate-sources` Maven phase for any plug-ins in your `pom.xml` that do generate any sources.

Comment: I must confess, that I am a newcomer in Java and Maven altogether. But did I understand correctly, that Intellij calls `mvn compile -f "pom.xml"` under the hood? I don't know how to trigger that action in VS Code, because the [Maven for Jave](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-maven)-extension seems to not provide a "generate-sources"-button.